# Angular 5 - Uncheck all checkboxes function is not affecting view

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, angular5

I'm trying to include a reset button on a Reactive form in Angular 5. For all form fields, the reset is working perfectly except for the multiple checkboxes, which are dynamically created.

Actually the reset apparently happens for the checkboxes as well, but the result is not reflected in the view.

**service.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="f" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <input type="hidden" id="$key" formControlName="$key">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" formControlName="name">
  </div>
  <br/>
  <p>Professionals</p>
  <div formArrayName="prof">
    <div *ngFor="let p of professionals | async; let i = index">
      <label class="form-check-label">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox (change)="onChange({name: p.name, id: p.$key}, $event.target.checked)" [checked]="f.controls.prof.value.indexOf(p.name) > -1"/>{{ p.name }}</label>
    </div>
    <pre>{{ f.value | json }}</pre>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" [disabled]="f?.invalid">Save</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" (click)="resetForm($event.target.checked)">Reset</button>
</form>
```

**service.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms'

import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Service } from './service';

export class ServiceComponent implements OnInit {

  f: FormGroup;

  userId: string;
  $key: string;
  value: any;
  services: FirebaseListObservable<Service[]>;
  service: FirebaseObjectObservable<Service>;
  professionals: FirebaseListObservable<Service[]>;
  profs: FirebaseListObservable<Service[]>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, 
              private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private route: ActivatedRoute, 
              private router: Router,
              private fb: FormBuilder) { 

    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if(user) this.userId = user.uid
        this.services = db.list(`services/${this.userId}`);
    })

    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if(user) this.userId = user.uid
        this.professionals = this.db.list(`professionals/${this.userId}`);
    })

  }

  ngOnInit() {   

    // build the form
    this.f = this.fb.group({
      $key: new FormControl(null),
      name: this.fb.control('', Validators.required),
      prof: this.fb.array([], Validators.required)
    })
  }

   onChange(name:string, isChecked: boolean) {
    const profArr = <FormArray>this.f.controls.prof;

    if(isChecked) {
      profArr.push(new FormControl(name));
      console.log(profArr.value);
    } else {
      let index = profArr.controls.findIndex(x => x.value == name)
      profArr.removeAt(index);
      console.log(profArr.value);
    }
  }

   resetForm(){
    let profArr = <FormArray>this.f.controls.prof;

    this.f.controls.name.setValue('');
    profArr.controls.map(x => x.patchValue(false));
    this.f.controls.$key.setValue(null);
   }
}
```

**service.ts**

```
export class Service {
    $key: string;
    name: string;
    professionals: string[];
  }
```

The result of the code above, displayed by line `<pre> {{f.value | json}} </ pre>` is:

*When I fill out the form:*

```
{
  "$key": null,
  "name": "Test service",
  "prof": [
    {
      "name": "Ana Marques",
      "id": "-LEZwqy3cI3ZoYykonWX"
    },
    {
      "name": "Pedro Campos",
      "id": "-LEZz8ksgp_kItb1u7RE"
    }
  ]
}
```

*When I click on Reset button:*

```
{
  "$key": null,
  "name": "",
  "prof": [
    false,
    false
  ]
}
```

But checkboxes are still selected:

[image]

What is missing?

Answer (score 2):

I would stop using FormControls to handle what is basically state.

You have some code which loads the `professionals` property of the component. Just add to that data a `checked` property and change the type of `professionals` to `Service[]`:

```
this.db.list(`professionals/${this.userId}`)
                          .subscribe(professionals => {
                            professionals.forEach(p => p.checked = false);
                            this.professionals = professional;
                          });
```

Btw, you don't have a checked property on your `Service` type, so either you extend it or transform `professionals` in something else (i.e. a `CheckableService`).

The template becomes:

```
<div *ngFor="let p of professionals; let i = index">
  <label class="form-check-label">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox (change)="onChange(p, $event.target.checked)" [checked]="p.checked"/>{{ p.name }}</label>
</div>
```

And the `onChange` method becomes:

```
onChange(professional: Service, isChecked: boolean) {
  professional.checked = isChecked;
  this.profArr = this.professionals.filter(p => p.checked);
}
```

It seems a lot cleaner to me (you will need to adjust for the checked parameter not being in the `Service` type, but the code is simply adaptable). No messing with controls, only data cleanly flowing through your component.

Answer (score 1):

You are not referencing your checkboxes. Give them a name using the index.

```
<div formArrayName="prof">
  <div *ngFor="let p of professionals | async; let i = index">
    <label class="form-check-label">
    <input [formControlName]="i" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox (change)="onChange({name: p.name, id: p.$key}, $event.target.checked)" [checked]="f.controls.prof.value.indexOf(p.name) > -1"/>{{ p.name }}</label>
  </div>
  <pre>{{ f.value | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried as you suggested now, but besides the same result as before, it displays the error on console: `Cannot find control with path: 'prof -> checkBox-0'` and `Cannot find control with path: 'prof -> checkBox-1'` (I have 2 checkboxes in this case).

Comment: You have to add them in your `prof: this.fb.array([], Validators.required)` too

Comment: Yes I got it, but how can I do this? May you give me a code snippet?

Comment: I just noticed that you are already pushing `FormControl` into the `FormArray`. Try replacing `formControlName="checkBox-{{i}}"`with just `[formControlName]="i"`

Comment: `[formControlName]="i"` brings the same result.

Comment: Sorry, actually the same error appears only for the **index 1**: `Cannot find control with path: 'prof -> 1'`. It seems that the **index 0** is working as expected.

Comment: Why are you iterating on `professionals` in your template and  pushing controls into the `FormArray` on `change` event ? Your `FormArray`should reflect your template

Comment: Either iterate on `f.controls['prof']` in your template, or initialize a `FormControl` for every professional in `ngOnInit()` depending on what you want to achieve

Comment: This form is for recording or updating services. In addition, I get the professionals and display a list with their names for the user to select (the checkboxes), in order to associate professionals with the service that will be saved. I am pushing the controls on `onChange` so this is the format recorded in `Firebase`. The functions **save** and **list** saved services (with their respective professionals) are working as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173921/discussion-between-atoyansk-and-youkouleley).

Answer (score -1):

This is my checkall checkbox

```
    <input type="checkbox" value="a" (click)="checkAll" [checked]="checkAll">
```

This i a regular checkbox, i used this whithin an ngfor

```
<input type="checkbox" value="a" (click)="check(object)" name="checkbox" [checked]="true">
```

And the checkall checkboxes function

```
let elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
 if (this.checkAll) {
      this.checkAll = false;
      for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
          elements[i].checked = false;
        }
      }
    }
else....the other way
```